# I can`t connect to MySQL Workbench database from VS Code

Tags: mysql, reactjs, database, visual-studio-code, mysql-workbench

I am trying to add an entry to the database in MySQL Workbench from VS Code during training with CRUD on ReactJS. But nothing works. All names and symbols match. When reloading the page, an entry should be added to the database. I'm press on "Execute the selected portion of the script" but nothing happens. Doesn't throw any errors. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?
MySQL 8.0, Windows 10.
File index.js

```
    const express = require("express")
    const app = express()
    const mysql = require("mysql")
    
    const db = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "123456",
        database: "gamedb",
    })
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO gamestab (gamename, gamedes) VALUES ('Diablo', 'Diablo is an action role-playing dungeon crawler video game series developed by Blizzard North.');"
        db.query(sqlInsert, (err, result) => {
            res.send('hello');
        })
    
    });
    
    app.listen(3001, () => {
        console.log('running 3001')
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved. I completely reinstalled MySQL, checked the MySQL80 operation in the services, specified the path to the System32 folder in PATH, replaced the chcp.com file from SysWOW64 to System32 (I had to set full user access to C drive Security), wrote the script:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
flush privileges;
```

In Manage Server Connection in the System Profile tab, I specified the system and paths, in VS Code I connected the MySQL management tool. That seems to be everything. As a result, it still didn’t connect, no entries were made through the back-end. In the end, in some random way, everything worked.